# Replace tag HTML automatically with php

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have a problem.

So, I am trying to make a script for replacing all tag HTML **'div'** by a tag like **'tr'**, **'td'** or **'table'**.

Must I use the other function PHP? I several HTML table, like that, and I must transform all script for a good table.

So, if you have an idea for me, it will be great :( Thank you!

My code :

```
$replace = array(
'<div style="display: table; width: 100%; border-spacing: 2px;">' => "<table style ='width: 100%; border-spacing: 2px;'>",
'<div style="display:table;width:100%;border-spacing: 2px;">' => "<table style ='width: 100%; border-spacing: 2px;'>",

'<div style="display: table-row; background: #dcdcba; color: #fff;">' => "<tr style='background: #dcdcba; color: #fff;'>",
'<div style="display: table-row;background: #dcdcba;color: #FFF;" >' => "<tr style='background: #dcdcba; color: #fff;'>",

'<div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">' => "<th style='padding: 6px 12px;'>",
'<div style="display: table-cell; padding:  6px 12px">' => "<th style='padding: 6px 12px;'>",

'<div style="display: table-row;">' => "<tr>",

'<div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">' => "<td style='padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;'>",
'<div style="display: table-cell; padding:  6px 12px;background-color: #eee">' => "<td style='padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;'>",

'</div>' => "</td>");


$newphrase = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace,  $value['description']);
```

THE CODE WRONG :

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; border-spacing: 2px;">
<div style="display: table-row; background: #dcdcba; color: #fff;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</div>
</div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
</div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
</div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
</div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
</div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;"> LoremIpsum</div>
</div>
```

MY EXPECTATIONS :

```
<table width: 100%; border-spacing: 2px;">
<th>
    <tr padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</tr>
    <tr padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</tr>
    <tr padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</tr>
    <tr padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</tr>
</th>

<tr>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum1991</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;"> LoremIpsum</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;"> LoremIpsum</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</td>
    <td padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). May I ask what's the use case for this? Where is the html coming from? It looks like it's rendered out of database data anyway.

Comment: You might be better off with a search&replace in your IDE... (I hope you don't want to use this in production time)

Comment: Just fyi: your expectations are invalid HTML

Comment: Sorry for the XY Problem.
I need do that, for transform, the bad synthax table in good synthax table ! Transfom all div in correctly tags.

Why my expectationd is invalid ?

Comment: after your edit the expected html is even worse...

Comment: Yeah, I understand but why ?

Comment: because it's invalid in so many places. `<table><th><tr></tr><tr></tr></th>...` should be `<table><tr><th></th><th></th></tr>...` for a start.

Comment: `<tr padding: 6px 12px;">` should be `<tr style="padding: 6px 12px;">`

Comment: Ahh okay, good.
I copy-paste the code. But it's really important for my question ? :D

Comment: _but_ you didn't answer the X Problem...

Comment: My exact problem is to want to transform my table with bad synthax into table to write into good synthax automatically. I can't explain more clearly than that… I'm not english really sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem is better to use PHP [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) Library and more specific [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.

Below I give you an example of how you can change divs to table

```
$content = '
    <div style="display: table; width: 100%; border-spacing: 2px;">
    <div style="display: table-row; background: #dcdcba; color: #fff;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px;">LoremIpsum</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;">LoremIpsum </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 6px 12px; background-color: #eee;"> LoremIpsum</div>
    </div>';

// Create a new DOM Document and load your old HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

// Create a new DOM Document
$newDom = new DOMDocument();

// Fetch all divs and append them to the new Document
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$table = null;
$row = null;
foreach($divs as $div) {
    $attributeString = getAttributeString($div);
    $type = getDivType($attributeString);
    $attributes = getAttributeList($attributeString);
    if ($type === 'table') {
        $table = $newDom->createElement('table');
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
            $table->setAttribute($key, $value);
        }
        $newDom->appendChild($table);
    } else if ($type === 'table-row') {
        if ($table) {
            $row = $newDom->createElement('tr');
            foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
                $row->setAttribute($key, $value);
            }
            $table->appendChild($row);
        }
    } else if ($type === 'table-cell') {
        if ($row) {
            $cell = $newDom->createElement('td', $div->nodeValue);
            foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
                $cell->setAttribute($key, $value);
            }
            $row->appendChild($cell);
        }
    }
}

// Get new HTML
echo $newDom->saveHTML();


/**
 * Get attribute list from attribute string
 */
function getAttributeList($attributeString)
{
    $list = [];
    $attributes = explode(';', $attributeString);
    foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attributeParts = explode(':', $attribute);
        if (count($attributeParts) > 1 && $attributeParts[0] != 'display') {
            $list[$attributeParts[0]] = $attributeParts[1];
        }
    }

    return $list;
}

/**
 * Get attribute string from a div element
 */
function getAttributeString(DOMElement $div)
{
    foreach($div->attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->name == 'style') {
            return str_replace(' ', '', $attribute->value);
        }
    }

    return '';
}

/**
 * Get div type from its attribute string
 */
function getDivType($attributeString)
{
    $styles = explode(';', $attributeString);
    foreach($styles as $style) {
        $styleParts = explode(":", $style);
        if ($styleParts[0] === 'display') {
            return $styleParts[1];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code will generate the following HTML

```
<table width="100%" border-spacing="2px">
   <tr background="#dcdcba" color="#fff">
      <td padding="6px12px">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px">LoremIpsum</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum </td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum</td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee">LoremIpsum </td>
      <td padding="6px12px" background-color="#eee"> LoremIpsum</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 ! Very good, but I have a problem, the attribute must be in a "style", else, the attribute don't work :/

Comment: So, it would be necessary to make : '<tr style="background:red; ....../>'

Comment: I try like that : $list['style'] = $attributeParts[0].": ".$attributeParts[1].";"; 
But only one arguments work  :/

Comment: The solution I proposed was a guideline. You can alter it as you like and use **style** and/or whatever other attribute you like

Comment: Yes, I succeeded perfect. Small problems, I have text before my table… and sometimes even after… Contained in tags<p> which them even contain tags <span> or <br>… How can I replace the text exactly or it was in the old document ? Thank you so much !

Comment: I am glad :) If you want, mark my answer as the solution https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks